# Narrow a dropdown search in JSP and using mysql db

Tags: java, mysql, jsp

```
<% 
ResultSet rsta=st.executeQuery("SELECT DISTINCT user_type FROM details where user_type not like 'null'");
while(rsta.next()) {
    out.write("<option value=" + rsta.getString("user_type") + ">" + rsta.getString("user_type") + "</option>");
}
%>
</select>
<label>Sct</label><select name="sct" id="subject" >
  <option selected="true" style="display:none;">Select Sct</option>
 <%  
  ResultSet rsta1=st.executeQuery("SELECT DISTINCT sct,user_type FROM details where sct not like 'null'"); 
  while(rsta1.next()) {
      out.write("<option value=" + rsta1.getString("sct") + ">" + rsta1.getString("sct") + "</option>");
  }
%> 
</select>
<label>Standard:</label><select name="standard" id="standard" >
<option selected="true" style="display:none;">Select Standard</option>
<% 
ResultSet rsta2=st.executeQuery("Select DISTINCT standard from details where standard not like 'null'");   
while(rsta2.next()) {
    out.write("<option value=" + rsta2.getString("standard") + ">" + rsta2.getString("standard") + "</option>");
}
%>
</select>
<label>Division:</label><select name="division"id="division" >
<option selected="true" style="display:none;">Select Division</option>
<%
ResultSet rsta3=st.executeQuery("Select DISTINCT division from details where division not like 'null'");   
while(rsta3.next()) {
    out.write("<option value=" + rsta3.getString("division") + ">" + rsta3.getString("division") + "</option>");
}
%>
</select>
```

These are 4 select fields.All the 4 get the list from the mysql database.
But all the selects get all the possible values from the database depending on the column selected.

I will give an example
While entering into the database suppose I add for the 4 columns a,1,cat,milk
2nd row consists of b,2,dog,bone.

Now in my above code I will get in the first select(a,b),second select(1,2) and so on.

I want the search to narrow,if I select a in the first select only 1 should appear n the second and cat in the third.How should I do this.
I am using JSP

Answer (score 2):

I first suggest you read a book on JSP cover to cover. We typically don't embed scriplets ( < % % >) in JSP pages anymore. Search amazon.com for beginning books on JSP that have good reviews and have been published within the last year or so. The book will most likely cover servlets too. you can also read up on JSTL. Reading the book can save you countless hours messing around with code fragments online and asking questions. You should be reading many books on Java and related technologies over time.

That being said:
The JSP page (presentation layer) is responsible for displaying data and handling user events (mouse clicks, etc). There should be no business logic or database logic in the page. In a very basic design, you have one and only one servlet that many JSP pages communicates with. When a person enters a url in his browser, the request goes to the servlet. The servlet calls business logic that in turn calls the database to get all the data it needs to initially populate the JSP page. The servlet puts the data in request scope (or session scope), then dispatches to the JSP page. The JSP page gets data from request scope to populate itself.

In answer to your question: populate the first dropdown upon initial page load (SQL call) via the servlet. The other dropdown boxes will be empty. When the user makes a selection in the first dropdown, have the page submit to the servlet. The servlet will read the first selected value and query the database to populate the second column. It will then dispatch to the JSP page to display the data in the first and second dropdown. A similiar operation occurs when the user selects an item in the second column.

 Lastly: read up on database design. Your database tables should be properly normalized. Also, you don't store a string value of 'null' in your datbase columns. You store an actual null instead.

Comment: Thanks alot for the info.But submitting a form after every selection does seem tedious.I had thought about it.But if you see it will be 3 times  i will have to submit the form

Answer (score 0):

The more professional approach is to use an ajax call to populate a dropdown box(s) rather than reload the entire form. Instead of raw ajax, I would recommend JQuery, which has ajax built in. Note Ajax calls are often generally used to alter an component on the browser and avoid repopulating the entire form. Another alternative is to store all the dropdown data in a multidimentional javascript structure and use oncick events to grab the selected item in one dropdown box to populate the next dropdown box. This way, there is no need to call back to the server (it all runs client side).